# Find intersections of two functions in Maple

Tags: maple

I have two functions $f$ and $g$ defined as:

$c:=x^3+x^2+x$

$d:=20\sin x^2-5$

I am trying to find the intersections of these using Maple $16$. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the command

> fsolve( x^3+x^2-x=20*sin(x^2)-5, x=0..2 );

If you give maple the above command you will get the answer

> $$ 0.4960649664. $$

Still there are other points of intersection and its your job to find them.

Comment: But it finds only one intersection. I would like to find all intercestions. In this example it is five.

Comment: But sorry, I made a mistakes in task.

I have two functions f and g defined as:

f:=x^3+x^2-x
g:=20sinx^2-5

Now it could be fine.

Comment: fsolve has an option: fsolve(eq, x, a..b).  Try a..b by -3..-2,then -2..-1, then -1..0, also 0..1, at last 1..2 .

Comment: @TonyPiccolo: Thanks for pointing that out. In fact, I knew about it and I wanted the OP to get started first. It seems he is new to maple.

Answer (score 1):

*I think you can use this command* :

> f := x^3+x^2+x = 0;
>
> g := 20*sin*x^2-5 = 0;
>
> fsolve({f, g});

[image]

Comment: :nice attempt$\color{red}{+1}$

Comment: I love the color! $\overset{+}{\uparrow}$

Comment: No, I don't think he hates you, nor does he want you to remove your account. He's just very modest/humble. That's all. I know he wants the best for all his students: and that means for you too!

Comment: I know how you feel: I want everyone to be happy, too. You do not make your best teacher unhappy. I am sure of that.

Comment: I am quite sure that you do not make your teacher unhappy. There is no reason for you to go away. He wants you to be happy, too. He would not want you to worry or be sad.

Comment: @amwhy I wish all the best for you and for my best teacher,too.
Forgive me,I'm going For sleep :)
Thank you again.I'm feeling good,Now <3

Comment: Sleep well, @Software! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy Thank you my friend ;)

Comment: Which comment was that?

Answer (score 1):

The two expressions `c` and `d` intersect at the values of x for which their difference is zero. So you can compute the roots of `c-d`, or plot that.

For this example it happens that all the roots fall within the default ranges of the two commands (`Roots` and `plot`) used below. For other examples you might supply additional arguments to specify the range.

```
c := x^3+x^2-x:

d := 20*sin(x^2)-5:

Student:-Calculus1:-Roots(c-d, numeric);

   [-3.372171392, -3.196493666, -2.489209992, -1.704885557, 

     -0.5361086923, 0.4960649664, 1.614439567]

plot(c-d);
```

[image]